# Can you get Warp terminal as the integrated terminal in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I followed the directions on Warp's documentation, but this only replaces the external terminal (it opens as a separate window).
https://www.warp.dev/blog/how-to-open-warp-vscode

I would like Warp to replace vscode's usage of xterm in the integrated terminal, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.
My attempt was to edit the profiles in my settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ],
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ]
        },
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ]
        },
        "tmux": {
            "path": "tmux",
            "icon": "terminal-tmux"
        },
        "pwsh": {
            "path": "pwsh",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "warp": {
            "path": "/Applications/Warp.app/Contents/MacOS/stable",
            "icon": "/Applications/Warp.app/Contents/Resources/Warp.icns"
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "warp",
```

but all this did was open up Warp in a separate window and the existing integrated terminal contained the output logs of Warp.

The Warp documentation doesn't include changing the integrated terminal and neither does the vscode documentation, so I highly suspect this is not feasible, but I was wondering if there was some less obvious workaround that someone might have found.

Comment: It should be better replacement for iTerm2 or something like that, not replacing zsh nor vscode internal terminal. But I wonder if we can have warp replacing our intergrated terminal in vscode, it should be possible if war create a vscode extension.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I guess that there's a misunderstanding of the terms
'warp' is a terminal emulator application
but VSCode integrates command shells like bash, zsh, etc.

terminal apps in most cases it's GUI apps that allow you to work with a command shell. In this case VSCode's terminal window it's a terminal app. that's why you can't just use 'warp' or any other GUI terminal emulator inside the VSCode environment.

Answer (score 14):

Replacing the vscode integrated terminal is a feature in the warp team's backlog, but one of the engineers says:

> "This is really really difficult eng wise. Just being transparent so people don't get their hopes up that this would come out anytime soon."

https://github.com/warpdotdev/Warp/issues/257#issuecomment-1274198741

Answer (score 6):

Once Warp starts building to WASM (looks like they're working on Windows, Linux, and WASM support), it might be embeddable into VS Code and/or Theia as a WebView Extension

Answer (score 5):

I have found a very workable solution. While it doesn't give some of the nice features of the integrated terminal such as the Javascript Debugger Terminal it is worth it for all other cases.

I just turn on the Warp Global Hotkey under Settings -> Features. I set the keybinding to `CMD-J` to override the VS Code hotkey that opens the integrated terminal. Then I set it to `Pin to bottom`, `Active Screen`, width of `100%` and height of `30%`.

With those settings I can just type `CMD-J` in VS Code and Warp opens up on the bottom 30% of the screen. The global hotkey mode is a separate process from the main warp app so you can still have Warp open as a separate terminal app while your global hotkey mode has its own tabs for your VS Code processes.

Comment: This worked for me, here is the docs if anyone wants to try it out, easier than it seems:

`settings -> features -> keys -> Global Hotkey`

https://docs.warp.dev/features/windows#global-hotkey

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Warp can't be accepted by vscode as the default integrated terminal.

> Value is not accepted. Valid values: null, "bash", "csh", "dash",
> "ksh", "sh", "tcsh", "zsh", "JavaScript Debug Terminal".

Comment: This is because vscode allows configuration of the shell - the values you listed are shells, not terminals.

Answer (score 1):

from https://www.warp.dev/blog/how-to-open-warp-vscode

1. VS Code > Settings > Preferences
2. Type "terminal" into the search bar
3. Where it says "Terminal > External: Osx Exec", replace whatever is there with "warp.app"
4. Now when you press Command + Shift + C, a new session of Warp should pop up.